# Add Two Spaces in a variable

Tags: bash, variable, aix, echo

I need to add two consecutive spaces to a variable. for e.g

I want to write `Feb  5` (with two spaces in-between) in a variable. I am using the following command but I get `Feb 5` instead. I am using AIX.

```
START_DATE=`echo $PREV_MONTH"  "$START_DAY`
```

Comment: Just curious— you’re using bash on AIX?

Comment: Note that if you see two spaces in between `Feb` and `5` in the output of `date` or `ls -l`, it's because the first one is the separator between the two fields and the second to pad the number to two characters for alignment. They output `Feb 15` with one space. So maybe you want `START_DATE=$(printf '%s %2d' "$PREV_MONTH" "$START_DAY")` here to get the same format.

Comment: It does work, (but over complex). How are you using it? You must quote when using.

Comment: Could START_DAY ever be 2 digits, and if so, do you still want two spaces between the pieces?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Hi Jeff, Yes Start Day can be 2 digits. i have implemented check to add two spaces only for Days < 10. It is working now though. thanks for help anyways. Cheers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the backtick construct here.  Simply

```
START_DATE="$PREV_MONTH  $START_DAY"
```

Now remember that you need to enclose `$START_DATE` inside `"` for it to retain spacing

```
$ PREV_MONTH=Feb
$ START_DAY=7
$ START_DATE="$PREV_MONTH  $START_DAY"
$ echo "$START_DATE"
Feb  7
$ echo $START_DATE
Feb 7
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the subshell notation `$()` instead of backticks, but that isn't your issue. Simply encapsulate your variables inside the double quotes along with any spaces.

```
START_DATE=$(echo "$PREV_MONTH  $START_DAY")
```

Double quotes allow for variable interpolation. If you had single quoted them, they would've been string literals.

But for your use case simply do this instead and forgo the `echo`, it's not necessary:

```
START_DATE="$PREV_MONTH  $START_DAY"
```